# What is wrong with this connection string?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can any one help me with this connection string. I can't manage how to fix.

```
Dim constring As String
        Dim con As SqlCeConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand
        constring = "(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + \\database.sdf;Password=pswrd;File Mode=shared read"
        con = New SqlCeConnection()
        con.Open()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string contains a piece of code that will now not be executed. I think you mean:

```
 constring = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\database.sdf;Password=pswrd;File Mode=shared read"
```

Comment: It says unknown connection option in connection string

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there are any other problems but definitely the code should be outside the string!

```
constring = String.Format("Data Source ={0}\\database.sdf;Password=pswrd;File Mode=shared read",(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase))
```

Comment: It says unknown connection option in connection string

Comment: See Edit. I think you need a `Data Source =` in there as well. My VB.NET might be slightly dodgy but should give you the idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use login details:

```
constring = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + \database.sdf; Password = pswrd"
```

But you don't have to:

```
constring = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + \database.sdf; Persist Security Info = false"
```

I tend to use the full file path:

```
constring = @"Data Source=C:\...\database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
```